# How to access Android.os.Build.MODEL in C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

In Android Studio using java, I can access the Android.os.Build.MODEL:  https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#MODEL.

I want to use this variable inside a C# plugin, how can we import or acquire access to it?

Answer (score 0):

In Xamarin, you can access to this [Model object](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.OS.Build.Model/).

I'm not used with Xamarin but it must be something like this :

```
public string DeviceModal {
    get {
        // read and return current device model
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(global::Android.OS.Build.Model) ?
            string.Empty :
            global::Android.OS.Build.Model.StartsWith(global::Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer) ?
            global::Android.OS.Build.Model :
            string.Format("{0} {1}", global::Android.OS.Build.Manufacturer, global::Android.OS.Build.Model);
    }
}
```